# Error in converting ERC20 tokens with decimals to full coins without rounding errors?

Tags: web3js, truffle, erc-20, bignumber

How to convert token to full token without having any rounding errors.

```
     web3.utils.toBN(6221221111111110001).div(10**18).toFixed()
```

TypeError: num.isZero is not a function
at BN.divmod (node_modules/number-to-bn/node_modules/bn.js/lib/bn.js:2329:17)
at BN.div (node_modules/number-to-bn/node_modules/bn.js/lib/bn.js:2425:17)
at Promise.all.then ()
at 
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:182:7)

```
        bal=6221221111111110001/ (10**(18))
```

It also has some precision errors.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The error-message implies that you are using `web3.utils.toBN`, not `web3.toBigNumber`. Please clarify your question.

Comment: And the expression `bal=balance/ (10**(18))` means nothing to us when we have no idea what `bal` and `balance` are. Please clarify that as well.

Comment: Also `12345 / 10 ** 15` is a value smaller than 1. If you plan to send it to a contract function, then you'll need to convert it to an integer, which means it's going to be a simple `0`. So what exactly are you trying to do here? Also, how on earth is that related to `bal=balance/ (10**(18))` at the end of the question?

Comment: @goodvibration Sorry for the typo.Updated the question

Comment: What do you mean "without having any rounding errors"? Function `web3.utils.toBN.div` gives you the integer division, do you want a regular division? You do realize that you will not be able to send the result to a contract function, right? In other words, it will be useful only on your offchain (Javascript) side.

Comment: Also, `BN` doesn't have function `toFixed`, but function `toString`.

Comment: @goodvibration I need to display the value in frontend exactly as 6.221221111111110001.
 But this 6221221111111110001/ (10**(18)) gives me the value as 6.22122111111.

Comment: TypeError: num.isZero is not a function   This is the error I got@goodvibration

Comment: Of course, but after you resolve this error, you'll get yet another error, telling you that class `BN` doesn't have a function `toFixed`. In any case, since you cannot use this class for non-integer computations, it won't matter for the sake of your goal here. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, regarding the specific error in your question, change this:

```
div(10**18)
```

To this:

```
divn(10**18)
```

Or to this:

```
div(web3.utils.toBN(10).pow(web3.utils.toBN(18)))
```

---

Second, since class `BN` supports only integer-arithmetic, the result of your computation is `6`.

in order to perform non-integer computation, you will need to use class `Decimal` instead:

```
const Decimal = require('decimal.js');
const str = Decimal(6221221111111110001).div(Decimal(10).pow(18)).toFixed();
```

Or simply:

```
const str = Decimal('6221221111111110001e-18').toFixed();
```

Note that you will not be able to send this result to a contract function.